# how to remove the title bar of a child form in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, mdi, formborderstyle

I am creating a MdiParent form in vb.net.
For that I have created the child form.
The child form's FormBorderStyle is none.
But while I open it on the MdiParent form, it shows the title bar at the bottom of the MdiParent form.
How can I remove it?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to show the child form

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are setting the MdiParent. here is some sample code that works for me:

```
Private Sub frmParent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True

    frmChild.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    frmChild.MdiParent = Me
    frmChild.Show()
End Sub
```